# How can I change the 'sed' slash (/) delimiter in insert command?

Tags: sed

Changing the delimiter slash (`/`) to pipe (`|`) in the substitute command of `sed` works like below

```
echo hello | sed 's|hello|world|'
```

How can I change the delimiter slash (`/`) to pipe (`|`) in the `sed` insert command below?

```
echo hello | sed '/hello/i world'
```

Comment: you can't and there's no need to

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'm guessing that the real-world example has a more complicated search pattern containing slashes. The real question is probably how to escape a string for pattern matching, which is covered elsewhere (e.g http://backreference.org/2009/12/09/using-shell-variables-in-sed/).

Comment: @AhmedMasud: yes you can, and the question demonstrates a need.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what is intended by the command you mentioned:

```
echo hello | sed '/hello/i world'
```

However, I presume that you want to perform certain action on lines matching the pattern `hello`.  Lets say you wanted to change the lines matching the pattern `hello` to `world`. In order to accomplish that, you can say:

```
$ echo -e "something\nhello" | sed '\|hello|{s|.*|world|}'
something
world
```

In order to match lines using a regexp, the following forms can be used:

```
/regexp/
\%regexp%
```

where `%` may be replaced by any other single character (note the preceding `\` in the second case).

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses) provides more details on this.

Comment: You should not have a delimiter after `i world`, it's just literal text at that point.

Comment: @cbuckley Maybe you wanted to add this comment to the question instead.

Comment: @tripleee The example that you're referring to came from the question.

Comment: @tripleee yup - typo on my part. Well spotted.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question asked is:

```
echo hello | sed '\|hello|i world'
```

That is how you would prepend a line before a line matching a path, and avoid Leaning Toothpick Syndrome with the escapes.